# Where to get free seafloor elevation for Galapagos Islands?

Tags: data, elevation, shaded-relief

I'm trying to find seafloor elevation around the Galapagos Islands. Something with resolution 30 - 100 meters.
Or just shaded relief for this region.
[image]

Comment: http://www.pmel.noaa.gov/eoi/staff/chadwick/galapagos.html

Comment: Thanks,
But I need the elevation as a raster layer to ArcGIS. But there are only .jpg
images.
Or maybe, I haven't understood something?

Comment: .grd & .e00 also available (ArcInfo Workstation) are available too see 'GETTING A COPY OF THE GRID OR THE RAW DATA:'

Comment: Oh, my fault. Didn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mapperz you could add that as an answer and the OP accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Bathymerty for the galapagos islands is available from.

http://www.pmel.noaa.gov/eoi/staff/chadwick/galapagos.html

GETTING A COPY OF THE GRID OR THE RAW DATA:

You are welcome to use this data in any publication or proposal, if it is accompanied by an acknowledgement such as "Bathymetric data compiled by William Chadwick, Oregon State University". If you would like to download a grid of this bathymetry (via ftp), click on one of the following links. The grid is available in GMT (Generic Mapping Tools) version 3 grid format ("**galap.grd**") or ArcInfo Interchange format ("**galp1000.e00**").

[image]
... Note, you probably need to click and hold down with your *right* mouse button and then choose "Save link as..." from the pop-up menu (this tells your browser that this is a binary file that you want to save to disk, not display on the screen, because it probably doesn't know what kind of file ends in *.grd or *.e00).